# How to export to excel using php when table data and header are dynamic?

Tags: php, excel

I want to export my code to excel however the header is also dynamic. Here is my code, i need assistance in exporting my data. This code below shows a dynamic table i showed in user view and needs to be exported. The view is:

"title: course/section"

"header: student id | student name | program | term | dynamic date 1 | Remarks (remarks why u are absent) including date 1 | date 2 | Remarks (remarks why u are absent) including date 2 | and so on.."

"table data: 20122222 |pinky webb |computer science | 3 | Absent | With medical certificate | present | no remark | present | no remark | late | no remark | and do on... "

"table data 2: 20122333 |Mane Sharpay|computer science | 3 | Absent | With medical certificate | present | no remark | Late | no remark | late | no remark | and so on... "

and so on...

basically, it shows the student and its attendance per date horizontally with a dynamic header of dates. sorry if im noob hehe but ill give a thumbs up i promise for ur effort

```
 <?php

    $query = "SELECT course_id, sections_id from current_att_view inner join professor_tbl on current_att_view.professor_id = professor_tbl.professor_id where professor_live_account = '".$_SESSION['username']."' group by course_id, sections_id";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    while ($col1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
    {
      $reslt;
      echo '<h3 class="course-sect">'.$col1[0].'/'.$col1[1].'</h3>';
      $qry = "Call Get_Attendance_Course_Section('".$_SESSION['username']."','".$col1[0]."','".$col1[1]."')";
      $reslt = mysqli_query($link, $qry);
      echo '<table class="table table-bordered">';
      echo '<tr>';
      if (!$reslt) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
        exit();
      }
      else{
        while ($fieldinfo = mysqli_fetch_field($reslt)) {

          if($fieldinfo->name != "Course" && $fieldinfo->name != "Section" && $fieldinfo->name != "Course Name" && $fieldinfo->name != "Schedule")
          {
            echo '<th>';
            echo $fieldinfo->name;
            echo '</th>';  
          }
        }
        echo '</tr>';
        while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($reslt))
        {
          for ($i=0; $i < (count($rows)/2); $i++) {
            if($i != 3 && $i != 4 && $i != 5 && $i != 6){
              echo '<td>';
              echo $rows[$i];
              echo '</td>';
            }
          }
          echo '</tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>';
        mysqli_next_result($link);
      }


    }


          // $reslt =mysqli_query($link, $qry);

    ?>

    <input type=hidden name=date value='<?php echo date("F d, Y",strtotime($date));?>'>
    <input type="hidden" name="outy" value="<?php echo $sql; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="export" value="Export" class="submit" />
```

Comment: Use the `$_GET['value here']` to complete your task

Comment: what do u mean by $_GET['value here'] :o